# Are there alternative ways to implementing an "active link" navigation without using server side languages?

Tags: jquery, html

By "active" I mean to have the link pointing to the current page classed as "active." This way the link's appearance can be modified using css.

Is it possible to implement an active link navigation without using a server side language? I would like to only use CSS/HTML/jQuery if possible. If there are, what are those methods? Assuming you want to create the following structure:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li class="active">Home</li>
   <li>About</li>
   <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you mean that you want the Home link highlighted when the user is on the Home page, likewise the Contact link, when on the contact page?

Comment: @scunliffe, yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @Harmen, let's assume you have static navigation, is it possible to implement something using jQuery, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 choices.

1. Serverside you determine which link is highlighted, and add the CSS class as you've done.
2. Per page you create, you manually add some JavaScript, that adds the class.

e.g. if you were using jQuery, you could do:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li id="home">Home</li>
   <li id="about">About</li>
   <li id="contact">Contact</li>
</ul>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contact').addClass('active');//set the Contact "tab" as the active link
  });
</script>
```

If at all possible though, I'd opt for #1... doing this server-side when you "build" the menu structure as this will be easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: If you're going to hard code that lump of JS into the page, then you might as well just put the class in the HTML to start with. Less code, no delay before it is executed, and executed by things without JavaScript. (And there's no such thing as a "CSS class". That's an HTML class).

Comment: @David Dorward - yes true... but I'm "presuming" in this case that the menu structure is built elsewhere and for whatever reason not-editable thus the class can't be added to the HTML directly.  As for the "CSS vs. HTML class" its a tricky call... the class is *created* in the HTML, *manipulated* in JavaScript, and *defined* in CSS, and *used* in CSS and JavaScript.  Since I do lots of work in the Java world, I often need to clarify that I'm talking about a CSS class, not a Java class... I choose not to use HTML class as to me that would be `HTMLSelectElement`, `HTMLInputElement`, etc. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in CSS can select an element based on an attribute containing a URL that resolves to the current URL.

You could handle this with JavaScript (examining `location`), but it would be trickier to handle there than with a server side system as multiple URIs can resolve to the same document and you would have to account for them all.

Comment: is using jQuery for this purpose common, or better? Or would you recommend against it?

Comment: Not common, not better. This is easier to handle on the server (or during the build stage of converting data and templates into static pages) then it is to hand off to the client.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented something similar to this using jQuery.
However my implementation was dependent on the URLs to the pages starting with the href's which worked out for me. (I used ASp.Net MVC and the URLs were in the structure that I can use for this.)

```
<ul id="nav">

            <li><a href='/Home'>Home</a></li>

            <li><a href='/Company'>Company</a></li>

            <li><a href='/Staffing'>Staffing</a></li>

            <li><a href='/Clients'>Clients</a></li>

        </ul>
<script>
    function setActiveMenu()
    {
        var curPage = window.location.pathname;
        curPage = (curPage.length>1)?curPage:"/Home";
        $("#nav > li > a").each
        (
            function(i, el)
            {
                var regEx = new RegExp("^" + $(el).attr("href") + "");
                if(regEx.test(curPage))
                {
                 $(el).parent().addClass("active");
                }
            }
        );
    }

$(setActiveMenu)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without class;

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}    /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;} /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}   /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

With JQuery;

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav li a').click(function() {
      $('#nav li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
  });
```

Comment: `a:active` != selected. It means the link that is currently being clicked, i.e. the mouse button is in its down state over this link.

Answer (score -2):

you could in javascript say(you need jquery)

```
  $('#active').onClick{
window.location: blabla.htm
}
```

Comment: See edited question, but it's to have the current page link classed differently so it can be modified using CSS.